# Prevent Google from indexing the no-www domain now that Google Search Console doesn't have a preferred domain setting

Tags: seo, domains, search-engine-indexing, no-www

I am hosting a Nuxt js app with Digital Ocean and I have my domain with godaddy.

I am facing a painful issue as godaddy does not accept alias and I actually can not change DNS provider at the moment.

I have set my cname www to the digital ocean provided domain and also do the correct 301 forwarding.

- `http://www...` is working
- `https://www...` is working
- `http://....` is working

but

`https://....` is not working and my "friend" google for some reason has chosen to index this url when someone search for my site online.

Is there any way to tell google to display my www and not the naked version?

I tried to follow this post [Request Removal of naked domain from Google Index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/request-removal-of-naked-domain-from-google-index) but the interface of google webmaster has changed and I can not find that setting

Please see my settings below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what type of hosting plan you have at digital ocean, but it should be possible to make your naked domain work with HTTPS.  I would try to get a security certificate that covers both your naked domain and www.  Such a cert is called a subject alternative name (SAN) certificate.  Then you could use the same certificate for HTTPS both with www and no-www.

Comment: "I have set my cname www to the digital ocean provided domain and also do the correct 301 forwarding." - What is configured exactly? That sounds like the CNAME is pointing to a different domain? How is the domain apex configured? And how/where are the 301 "forwarding" configured?

Comment: I am out now but as soon as I back home I will show you my set up! My current website is https://www.theironfairies.com /// I have added the domain in digital ocean without the www but I have no way to verify the ownership

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I hav added my settings

Comment: You probably can't use forwarding functionality from the DNS panel to get HTTPS to to work.  Most DNS providers that offer forwarding don't support HTTPS.  You can usually use an `A` record to send requests for the naked domain to your web server and handle the redirection there.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller A record force me to point to an specific IP... the whole idea of using OceanDigitals is not to be forced to a fix IP so in case there is downtime they can moved the resource to other available

Comment: Can you use digital ocean themselves as your DNS host by changing your NS records at GoDaddy?   GoDaddy doesn't offer ANAME or ALIAS records that would help in this case.  Also their redirects are [pretty broken](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I can not... I guess I wil need to force my employer to do it! Wish me luck haha